# Inequalities Theorem Proof

Tags: inequality

While studying, I read that the solutions of $f(x)/g(x)<0$ is equal to the solutions of $f(x)*g(x)<0$. I don't get why this is so. Could someone explain the reason the solutions to these two inequalities are the same?

Comment: What theorem? It's not very clear what you're asking here IMO.

Comment: I only see one inequality in your question.  What is the expression with $f(x)g(x)$ supposed to say?

Comment: I am quite sure (s)he also means $f(x)g(x)<0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is defined and $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < 0 $ if and only if

$f(x)>0$ and $g(x)<0$, or $f(x) < 0 $ and $g(x)>0$.

The same is true for the equation $f(x)g(x) <0$ .

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, $g(x)\not =0$ Therefore, multiplying both sides of the inequality with the positive number $(g(x))^2$ would not change the sign of the inequality. Thus $$\dfrac {f(x)}{g(x)}<0\implies \dfrac {f(x)}{g(x)}\times (g(x))^2<0\implies f(x)\times g(x)<0$$

Answer (score 0):

The rule of signs is the same for products and for quotients, that's all.